# access 2016 - compare two tables and return matched records using query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My goal is to create a query, macro or any solution that can do the task described below.

1. Lets say I have an access 2016 table named "student" with 12 records like this:

[image]

2. And then, lets say I have a second table named "matchme" with 4 records like this:

[image]

I need to find a way to

=> first, create a query that returns result of "graduation_date" are equal to Date "1/31/2017" from Table "student" .

=> second, from the result returned from first step, create a query that compare "email" from "student" table with "email" from "matchme" table, and return the [matched] record result.

So the desired result would be:

[image]
since the email gary@xxx.com and thomas@xxx.com exist in both tables.

How can I create a query like this?

you can download my access file from here: [experiment.accdb](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45124498329747447576)

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your data sample you need  a join  on date and name between the two tables

```
select * from student 
inner join matchme on student.graduation_date = matchme.graduation_date 
                        and student.email = matchme.email

where student.graduation_date  = '1/31/2017'
```

Comment: I apologize. I made a mistake when I was uploading the question. I corrected my question. it is the "email" field that has to match.. Could you revise your answer to new question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I pasted the sql, and it says "the specified filed 'graduation_date' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement."  Any idea if i am doing anything wrong? Even if i change the where clause to where student.graduation_date  = '1/31/2017' it returns "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
select * from student 
inner join matchme on student.email = matchme.email                       
where student.graduation_date  = '1/31/2017'
```

Comment: Let me know if I did something wrong. 1) Click “Create” 2) Click the “Query Design” button. 3) Saw a “Show Table” dialog box 4) Click close on this dialog box without selecting any tables. 5) Select the “SQL View” from View 6) pasted the code you wrote here. 7) Click Run => The result is coming up as "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the data types on the 2 email fields are different. If you are using Access use Text data type. Check both email fields on student and matchme tables, set both to Text data type in design view

Comment: hi thank you for your reply.  The ID is AutoNumber for both tables. student_number, first_name, last_name, email are Short Text for both tables.  graduation_date is Date/Time for both tables.. hmmmm  you can actually download my file as i added the link in the original post if you are curious.. thank you...